# Who taught Kawaki fire style?

Tags: boruto

I wanted to know who taught Kawaki fire style.  I always thought it was Naruto, because I think I saw him teaching it to Kawaki, but I have seen some people say Sarada taught him.

So who taught him?

Comment: It's possible, as you mentioned, Naruto and Sarada teaching Kawaki is possible. Sarada has it, and Naruto has access to all five *basic* elemental chakra natures.